# Plug Two Monitors into a Single DisplayPort

Tags: multiple-monitors, display-port

I'm aware that you can daisy-chain [DisplayPort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Multi-Stream_Transport_(MST)) monitors so that two monitors end up being plugged into a single port on the computer. However, the DisplayPort monitors I've purchased do not have the out-ports that would be necessary for daisy-chaining.

Is there a splitter device, that I can purchase, that would allow me to plug two DisplayPort monitors into DisplayPort, and then plug only that device into the single DisplayPort that's on the computer (in a manner where both monitors would work at the same time, as though they were daisy-chained)?

So far, I've found splitters similar to the device I'd wanting, but those will only allow one monitor to work at a time. I'm look for a device that will allow both monitors to be used at the same time (as though the computer had multiple displayports.

Comment: I bought *one* of these for $64.06 : [2-Port Multi Monitor Adapter](https://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/B00XXPYGPO/howtoadvicecom), but I hoping these devices become less expensive in the future, because I'd really like to buy several of them, but I won't do that until the price comes down.

Comment: You should post that as an answer and mark it as the correct answer.